# Why would a user agent string contain both "Samsung" and "AppleWebKit"?

Tags: apache, user-agent, logs

Investigating an issue on a website, I see an entry in the Apache log with this User Agent setting:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 8.0.0; SAMSUNG SM-G955U Build/R16NW) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) SamsungBrowser/7.0 Chrome/59.0.3071.125 Mobile Safari/537.36
```

How can it be both Samsung and Apple? How do I map this to an actual browser type and version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps they are running Safari on Android https://safariforwindowspc.com/safari-web-browser-android-download/

Comment: I am not sure you saw it, but if you scroll the agent string to the right, it is safari mobile.